# How to insert the error message in table

Tags: sql-server, insert-update, error-logging

I am working on a project, in my project I am stuck in a scenario, where i need to maintain a error log. I created a `error log` table in which i have column name `Error Message`. I want to insert the error message in that column.for ex I am using a identity column, now if someone insert a value for that identity column without using "Set Identity On" then a error message is displayed like "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'example' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF." i want that error message to be as record in my table.

Table Structure

```
create table example
(
  id int identity(1,1),
  code int not null,
  startdate date not null,
  enddate date null,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_example] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [id] ASC
  ),

  constraint uc_combination UNIQUE(code,startdate,enddate)
)on [primary]
```

Error Log Table

```
Create table errorlog
(
  errorid int identity (1,1),
  Errordate datetime,
  ErrorMessage Nvarchar(255)
) on [primary]
```

In Errorlog table in column error message i want to show those error message which occur while inserting the records in example table.

How should I achieve that.

Your help will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the structure of the table you are using, and the command that you are using to perform the insert.  Offhandedly, I question why you want to set the identity value of an error _log_ table.

Comment: Hi Brendan, this was just an example. I want to insert all those error message in a table that doesnot allow to insert a record.

Comment: Right - example or not, we probably need to see what your table structure is so that we can help.  Why does your table not allow you to insert?

Comment: I added table structure of two tables example and errorlog. if the unique constaraint is violet than the error message should be inserted in errormessage column of errorlog table

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is to use a TRY...CATCH block:

```
DECLARE @DUPDATE AS DATETIME

SELECT @DUPDATE = GETDATE()    

BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO Example(code, startdate, enddate)
    VALUES (1, @DUPDATE, @DUPDATE)

    -- Second insert should violate the constraint...
    INSERT INTO Example(code, startdate, enddate)
    VALUES (1, @DUPDATE, @DUPDATE)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Execute the error retrieval routine.
    INSERT INTO ERRORLOG(ErrorDate, ErrorMessage)
    VALUES (GETDATE(), ERROR_MESSAGE())
END CATCH;
```

Comment: Which columns does ERRORLOG have?